# Why Visual Studio's Database Profiler shows "unknown" results?

Tags: database, visual-studio, .net-core, profiler

I'm trying to use Visual Studio's Database Profiler following Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/analyze-database?view=vs-2019).
Everything seems to work as described but in the report, I get `unknown` values, except very few queries (4 out of hundreds) in which all data are populated (screenshot is cut).
Any ideas why this is happening?

[image: profiler report]

Visual Studio version: Community 2019, Version 16.9.5.

Comment: This is happening for me to, no documentation or troubleshooting information exists. VS 2022.

Comment: I have the same problem... Did you find any resolution? I have every row as unknown, not just few as you have

Comment: I have the same problem VS2022, Version 17.3.6